# Why is this array element access orders of magnitude faster than array view\slice?

Tags: scala

I'm writing a simple string parenthesis balance checking app as a part of parallel programming course. 
I have two implementations of the sequential part of the application - one that traverses given `Array[Char]` using the index, and the second one that uses the head\tail methods.

I can't understand why for my test data (100000000-long array) the by-index access is orders of magnitude faster than the head\tail alternative.

Scalameter reports (#elements in the test collection: 100000)

- Sequential array: : average execution time: 0.10 ms + no GC
- head\tail + (chars.view(idx, until)): average execution time: ~949.07ms + medium amount of GC
- head\tail + (chars.slice(idx, until)): average execution time: 603.42ms + medium amount of GC
- List head\tail (chars.slice(idx, until)): average execution time: 3.41 ms + medium amount of GC
- List head\tail (chars.view(idx, until)): I terminated the test after over 45s (!) + lots of lots of GC

I understand that the view method should create a lazy view of the collection and the slice method actually materializes the chunks of the collection - this explains the differences in GC calls. I cannot however understand the differences in execution time.

- What is the cause of the differences in execution time between the index approach and the head\tail approaches?
- Why does the head\tail slice version perform better than the view one? I expected the result to be the other way around.

Full code of the method under test (for the List version of the tests the collection was transformed to list, outside of the measured time):

```
  def parBalance(chars: Array[Char], threshold: Int): Boolean = {

    def traverse(idx: Int, until: Int, initialUnmatchedLeft: Int, initialUnmatchedRight: Int): (Int, Int) = {

      def traverseChunkSeq(chars: Seq[Char], unmatchedLeft: Int, unmatchedRight: Int): (Int, Int) =
        if (chars.isEmpty) (unmatchedLeft, unmatchedRight)
        else chars.head match {
          case '(' => traverseChunkSeq(chars.tail, unmatchedLeft + 1, unmatchedRight)
          case ')' =>
            if (unmatchedLeft > 0) traverseChunkSeq(chars.tail, unmatchedLeft - 1, unmatchedRight)
            else traverseChunkSeq(chars.tail, unmatchedLeft, unmatchedRight + 1)
          case _ => traverseChunkSeq(chars.tail, unmatchedLeft, unmatchedRight)
        }

      def traverseChunk(i: Int, unmatchedLeft: Int, unmatchedRight: Int): (Int, Int) =
        if (i < until) (unmatchedLeft, unmatchedRight)
        else chars(i) match {
          case '(' => traverseChunk(i + 1, unmatchedLeft + 1, unmatchedRight)
          case ')' =>
            if (unmatchedLeft > 0) traverseChunk(i + 1, unmatchedLeft - 1, unmatchedRight)
            else traverseChunk(i + 1, unmatchedLeft, unmatchedRight + 1)
          case _ => traverseChunk(i + 1, unmatchedLeft, unmatchedRight)
        }


//      traverseChunk(idx, initialUnmatchedLeft, initialUnmatchedRight)
      traverseChunkSeq(chars.view(idx, until), initialUnmatchedLeft, initialUnmatchedRight)
//      traverseChunkSeq(chars.slice(idx, until), initialUnmatchedLeft, initialUnmatchedRight)
    }

    def reduce(from: Int, until: Int): (Int, Int) = {
      if (until - from <= threshold) traverse(from, until, 0, 0)
      else {
        val medium = (until + from) / 2
        val ((lo, lc), (ro, rc)) = parallel(reduce(from, medium), reduce(medium, until))
        (math.max(0, lo - rc) + ro, lc + math.max(0, rc - lo))
      }
    }

    reduce(0, chars.length) == (0, 0)
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing because `chars.tail` makes a copy of the array (without the first element). Try it with `List`? The difference should be less dramatic.

Comment: I'll try to use Lists later, but what I'd expect is that the tail operation on view of a collection will just shrink the view, not create a copy of the view - is this not the case?

Comment: What times do you get with the `slice` version? Also, `views` aren't free, there's an overhead in using them. So in cases where you're eventually going to evaluate all elements anyway (as in your case) they're just going to make things slower.

Comment: I've modified the question to fix a copy\paste error - the last measurement was for the slice version. It performs better than the view one but still orders of magnitude worse than indexed one. Why is this? Shouldn't the slice perform worse because of materializing the collection right away? I've also added the performance characteristics for the list versions - they are much better than the array ones but still worse than sequential traversal. Is this score limited by the traversal required for slice\view operations? Can it be improved by using different operations?

Comment: For the time being I'll conclude that the different is the effect of excessive array chunk copying \ list data traversal. I'd however still like to know why the `tail` operation of view of a collection performs a full array copy - I tried to verify the source code but I'm not yet able to figure it out myself.